# SSL Handshake Failed - Java 1.8

Tags: java, security, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

Just letting folks know about an issue I had that many seemed to have had after upgrading to Java 1.8.  Not all of the solutions are the same hence posting how I resolved this.

But first... This is not a solution worthy of production systems since security is being effectively downgraded.  However, if you are blocked testing etc. it is probably quite suitable.

My issue was that no matter what I did... enabled SSLv3 etc. I always received

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure".
```

Here are the steps I took to 'solve' this.

First, I discovered which cipher the server was using.  I did this via openssl.

```
openssl s_client -host yourproblemhost.com -port 443
```

This yields (at the end...)

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
```

Now.. what do we use 'Java-wise' to enable that cipher?

[Oracle link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19728-01/820-2550/cipher_suites.html)

In that link, it has the names and their Java counterpart.  So for RC4-MD5, we have SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.

ok good.  Now I added a System property.

```
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

And in my code...

```
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "" /*disabledAlgorithms */ );
```

Again.. **this is an absolute last resort 'fix'**... But if you're hitting your head aganst a wall to get it running (for testing), I hope it comes in useful.

Answer (score 5):

With [JDK 1.8.0_51 release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u51-relnotes-2587590.html) RC4 is no longer supported from Java as client (also as server) to negotiate SSL handshake, RC4 is considered weak (and compromised ) cipher and that is the reason for removal

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8076221

You can still however enable it by removing RC4 from `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` from your Java security config or progamatically enabling them using `setEnabledCipherSuites()` method

However better solution would be to update the server configuration (if it is under your control) to upgrade to stronger Ciphers

> RC4 is now considered as a compromised cipher. RC4 cipher suites have been removed from both client and server default enabled cipher suite list in Oracle JSSE implementation. These cipher suites can still be enabled by `SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites()` and `SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites()` methods.

As to your approach on setting it by using `Security.setProperty()`, it is not reliable way because the [fields which hold disabled algorithms are static and final](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/security/ssl/SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java#49), So if that class gets loaded first you don't have controll over it, you could alternatively try by creating a properties file

like this

```
## override it to remove RC4, in disabledcipher.properties
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DHE
```

and in your JVM, you could refer it as system property like this

```
java -Djava.security.properties=disabledcipher.properties blah...
```

Answer (score 2):

RC4 was effectively cracked - [14 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluhrer,_Mantin_and_Shamir_attack#Background).

> The Fluhrer, Mantin and Shamir (FMS) attack, published in their **2001
>   paper** "Weaknesses in the Key Scheduling Algorithm of RC4", takes
>   advantage of a weakness in the RC4 key scheduling algorithm to
>   reconstruct the key from encrypted messages.

The problem isn't in Java 8.

The problem is your server is using RC4.

Comment: In my comment I had..

"However better solution would be to update the server configuration (if it is under your control) to upgrade to stronger Ciphers"


Yes.. It's a server issue.  And that is the problem.  I only posted this to provide a work around until servers (that could very well be out of the developer's control) can be fixed.

Cheers,


James

Answer (score -1):

Thanks alton for sharing such a life saver information.
Only one thing I'd like to change
since

```
openssl s_client -host yourproblemhost.com -port 443
returned ->
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : 0000
openssl s_client -connect X.X.X.X:993  -prexit -tls1
returned -> the expected response as
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : RC4-MD5
```