# Enabling AES_128_CBC and RC4_128 for JDBC connections to MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, java-8, jtds, rc4-cipher, beast

To ensure backward compatibility of my application, I'm testing JDBC over TLS behaviour when an *MS SQL Server* version vulnerable to [CVE-2011-3389](https://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-3389) is used (any 2005, or 2008/2008R2 w/o service packs fit). In theory, two options are available:

- either disable CBC protection via `-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false` and continue to use a block cipher such as `AES_128_CBC` or `3DES_EDE_CBC`,
- or fall back to a stream cipher such as `RC4` (yes I'm aware this is insecure, too, due to [CVE-2015-2808](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2015-2808)).

In practice, while I have no trouble establishing a connection using `3DES_EDE_CBC` with CBC protection off, I'm still unable to use `RC4_128` using an JDK newer than **1.8.0_51** (which happened to [address](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u51-relnotes-2587590.html) CVE-2015-2808) or `AES_{128,256}_CBC` (using any **1.6+** JDK).

Here's the results broken down by Java version:

- **1.6.0_45** (*jTDS*)

  - `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` is used
- **1.7.0_76** (*jTDS*) and any 1.8.0 up to **1.8.0_45** (*MS SQL JDBC*):

  - `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` (default) or `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` can be used
  - won't use `AES_128_CBC` even if `3DES` is disabled (`3DES_EDE_CBC` will be forced anyway)
- **1.8.0_45** (IBM J9 8.0 SR1) (*MS SQL JDBC*)

  - `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` is used (successful only if CBC protection is off), also if either `AES` or `RC4` is requested
- **1.8.0_51+** (Oracle) (*MS SQL JDBC*)

  - `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` is used (successful only if CBC protection is off),
  - won't use `AES_128_CBC` or `AES_256_CBC` even if requested (unlike previous  Java versions, `3DES` is no longer forced, instead I get an `IOException` after `ClientHello`, which does list `*_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` as compatible ciphersuites)
  - won't use `RC4` even if both with `AES` and `3DES` are disabled: `"no negotiable cipher suite"` (both *jTDS* and *MS SQL JDBC*).

Here's the `java.security` I use to request `AES`:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, 3DES_EDE_CBC
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
        K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
        RC4_128, RC4_40
```

and here's the version to request `RC4`:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, AES_128_CBC, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, AES_256_CBC, AES_128_GCM, AES_256_GCM, 3DES_EDE_CBC
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
        K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL
```

Questions:

- Apparently, `AES_{128,256}_CBC` is supported by my Java clients, as I can use `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` when connecting to *MS SQL Server 2014*. Can anyone confirm it is **not** supported by *MS SQL Server 2005*? Since disabling `AES` effectively leads to `"no negotiable cipher suite"`, I assume it **is** supported, but something happens server-side, even though CBC protection is off.
- How can I still use `RC4` in Java **1.8.0_51+**? [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048221/1343979) no longer works, nor has any effect `https.cipherSuites` system property (described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/coffeys/entry/jdk_and_use_of_rc4)). There's a magical `jdk.tls.enableRC4CipherSuites` system property in [6u115](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142326) and [7u101](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141050), but it seems to have no effect in Java 1.8.
- What the heck is wrong with *jTDS*? It works fine with Java 1.6 and 1.7 (driver versions 1.2.8 and 1.3.1), but using Java 1.8 I'm constantly receiving `"Connection reset by peer"` whenever *MS SQL JDBC* would just use `3DES` to encrypt connection data.

Comment: We found the same issue with jTDS and JDK 1.8. There are numerous posts about it. There appear to be some unofficial patches available: [jTDS patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/725/?limit=10&page=1#7b2b) We have decided not to push these patches to production but instead go with a commercial driver that supports later JDKs and versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @coffelka I would appreciate any informative links you have about this issue. I am just happening upon it now and need to catch up.

Comment: What does this have to do with Beast?